# Got memory leak; how to free this malloc?

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, cs50

```c
bool check(const char *word)
{
    int length = strlen(word);

    //malloc size of char times length of word plus \0
    char *lower_case = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + 1));
    lower_case[length + 1] = '\0';

    //change characters to lowercase
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        lower_case[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }

    //generate int hash
    int index = generate_hash(lower_case);

    node_ptr trav = hashtable[index];

    while (trav != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(trav->word, lower_case) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        trav = trav -> next;
    }
    free(lower_case);

    return false;
}
```

I got 27 bytes of memory leaked from a Valgrind test; how to free it?

Comment: It might help if you post a [mcve] as there may other leaks/issues in your code. But for the leak, you can do `free(lower_case);` before `return true;`.

Comment: If you have a problem report from Valgrind, include the problem report in the question.  You didn't mention Valgrind complaining about the out-of-bounds memory access, but it did complain.  You also need to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)), as already noted by others.

Comment: Style guide: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3).
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing `trav -> next` is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `trav->next`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `lower_case[length + 1] = '\0';` writes out of bounds, change to `[length]`.
- You are missing `#include <stdlib.h>` and other necessary includes.
- You create a memory leak each time you execute `return true;`.
- Never hide pointers behind typedefs, as taught by crap classes like CS-50.

You should be able to fix the code along the lines of this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool check (const char *word) 
{ 
  size_t length = strlen(word);

  char* lower_case = malloc(length + 1);
  if(lower_case == NULL)
  {
    return false;
  }

  //change characters to lowercase
  for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    lower_case[i] = tolower(word[i]);
  }
  lower_case[length] = '\0'; 

  //generate int hash
  int index = generate_hash(lower_case); 
  bool result = false;
  for(const node* trav = hashtable[index]; trav!=NULL; trav=trav->next)
  {
    if (strcmp(trav->word, lower_case) == 0)
    {
        result = true;
        break;
    }
  }

  free(lower_case);
  return result;
}
```

The type `node_ptr` needs to be changed into `node` without hidden pointers.

Answer (score 0):

There's an out of bounds access immediately after `malloc`.

Here, you're accessing out of bounds:

```
lower_case[length + 1] = '\0';
```

It should be:

```
lower_case[length] = '\0';
```

It's also a sensible idea to check if `malloc` failed, too!

As noted in comments, there's also a case when memory leak can happen when returning from inside the loop. You need to free there:

```
  if (strcmp(trav->word, lower_case) == 0)
    {
        free(lower_case);
        return true;
    }
```